# How to use OPC UA-ModelCompiler with multiple xml model input files?

Tags: opc-ua

I've used succesfully UA-ModelCompiler from OPCFoundation (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler) for compiling my xml model, using the following format:

```
OPC.UA.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\MyOpcUaBasic.xml" -cg ".\MyOpcUaBasic.csv" -o2 ".\MyOutputFolder"
```

I'd like to compile another OPC UA xml model that uses more than one namespace declared at the beginning of the model.
Example:

```
<Namespaces>
    <Namespace Name="MyOpcUaBasic" Prefix="Opc.Ua.Basic" XmlPrefix="MyOpcUaBasic">http://Myorganization.it/Basic/"</Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="MyOpcUaBasic2" Prefix="Opc.Ua.Basic2" XmlPrefix="MyOpcUaBasic2">http://Myorganization.it/Basic2/"</Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="OpcUa" Prefix="Opc.Ua" XmlPrefix="OpcUa" XmlNamespace="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd">http://opcfoundation.org/UA/</Namespace>
</Namespaces>
```

So I need more than one xml input to generate my xml nodeset.
I have tried the following:

```
OPC.UA.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\MyOpcUaBasic.xml" -cg ".\MyOpcUaBasic.csv" -d2 ".\MyOpcUaBasic2.xml" -cg ".\MyOpcUaBasic2.csv" -o2 ".\MyOutputFolder"
```

But it does not work giving an error.
How should I do?
It is possible the usage is not right, but I have't found how to use more than one input xml to create my nodeset, if this is possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I forgot the FilePath field

```
  <Namespace Name="MyOpcUaBasic" Version="1.00" PublicationDate="2020-05-27T00:00:00Z" Prefix="Opc.Ua.SmBasic" XmlPrefix="MyOpcUaBasic" XmlNamespace="http://Myorganization.it/OpcUa/ServicesModel/Basic/Types.xsd" FilePath="MyOpcUaBasic">http://Myorganization.it/Basic/</Namespace>
```